# Function bounded at large values of t?

Tags: control-theory

using laplace I've calculated the output of my system  as:
$$-\frac1{104} \exp(-5t)  + \frac18\exp(-t) +\frac1{26}(2\sin(t)-3\cos(t))$$
I've been told that this  is bounded from above and below at large values of t. Why is this true at large values of t and what are the bounds?

Comment: For all $t\geq 0$, $0<e^{-t}\leq 1$, $|\sin(t)|\leq 1$ and $|\cos(t)|\leq 1$.

Comment: For the algebra:
$$
2\sin{t} - 3\cos{t} = \sqrt{13} \sin{\left( x-\tan^{-1}{\frac{3}{2}} \right)} \Rightarrow -\sqrt{13} \leq 2\sin{t} - 3\cos{t}  \leq \sqrt{13}
$$